# What verb would describe the relationship between a C# class and its Attribute?

Tags: c#, attributes, naming-conventions

Considering the following:

```
[Export]
public class BudgetView : ViewBase, IView
{
    // Members Galore
}
```

It is clear that you would say `BudgetView` *extends* `ViewBase`, and it *implements* `IView`, but what does it to to poor old `Export`?

Perhaps `BudgetView` *uses* `Export`?
Or `BudgetView` *applies* `Export`?

I need this for my documentation.  I'm need to be very formal and very detailed.

**Edit:**

[image]

My UML tool is very restrictive about what I can and cannot do.  I cannot make custom stereotypes for instance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[MSDN uses the terminology](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0w1kczw.aspx) of "applies."  Export is *applied to* the BudgetView *type*.

The C# Specification, Version 4 uses this terminology as well.  For example, from **1.12 Attributes**:

> Attributes can be applied by giving their name, along with any arguments, inside square brackets just before the associated declaration. If an attribute’s name ends in Attribute, that part of the name can be omitted when the attribute is referenced.

Comment: @Reed, So you would say, "BudgetView applies Export?" Because that is the verbage I need to express. :)

Comment: +1. However, for documentation I would say it would be on a case by case basis. The documentation for ExportAttribute states 'Specifies that a type, property, field, or method provides a particular export.'. However, if it was a serializable attribute, I would say the class is able to be serialized/serializable.

Comment: @Jordan: No - I'd say Export is applied to BudgetView.  If you must say it from the POV of BudgetView, I'd say "BudgetView has Export applied"

Comment: The phrasing seems awkward to me.

Comment: @ChaosPandion: True, but it's what's used through MSDN and the C# spec.

Comment: @Reed: OK, I'm trying to define the relationship between two classes that I have created ultimately in UML. See the image above.

Comment: @Jordan: UML doesn't really have a technique for handling attributes.  I would, probably, handle this differently to avoid having it look like inheritance.  That being said, the attribute is always applied to a member or type, in C# spec.  If you want it in your diagram, I'd probably flip the arrow around and use "Applied"

Comment: @Reed: That's a dependency arrow, not inheritance.  It simply specifies that BudgetDetailsView depends on ExportViewMetaData because it applies it-- is applied by.

Comment: @Jordan: I know - but still, it looks odd.

Comment: @Reed: That it does, but I need to contain it in my documentation.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps BudgetView is *attributed* by Export. Or you could use a term from Java and say Export annotates BudgetView.

Answer (score 0):

I would have to say:

> BudgetView declares Export

Answer (score 0):

A dotnet attribute is similar to a uml stereotype

```
<<Export>> 
BudgetView
```